# import scala.io.StdIn

Tags: eclipse, scala, stdin, scala-ide

I'm using Eclipse ScalaIDE and for some reason I'm not able to

```
import scala.io.StdIn
```

I'm getting a red squiggly that tells me:

> object StdIn is not a member of package io

And I'm seeing that it's not in that scala.io jar file. The ScalaDoc, however says it should be there. I've tried both scala 2.10.4 and 2.11.5. I've used the Eclipse ScalaIDE to create the scala project and I've also created an sbt eclipse project directly using the `scalasbt.plugin` which I use all the time to manage ScalaIDE dependencies.

```
sbt "eclipse with-source=true"
```

Neither way is getting it.

I'm currently taking the Coursera Reactive Programming course and an assignment file has this import. I'm able do compile the project with sbt directly, but Eclipse ScalaIDE is not doing the job. Any clues? There may be good reason why not to use `scala.io.StdIn`, but my question is why can I not get it to import in the ScalaIDE?

thank you

Comment: Are you sure you are using 2.11.5 in ScalaIDE? `scala.io.StdIn` wasn't added until 2.11.x, so it would explain why you get the error in 2.10.4

Comment: @ArneClaassen I bet you that's it. Thanks! I did find, also, that def readLine is part of the Predef.class so the import isn't actually needed.

Comment: @ArneClaassen Yes, that was the answer. If you post an answer I'll accept it. Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`scala.io.StdIn` is new in scala 2.11.x and does not exist in previous versions.

The problem you are likely encountering is that ScalaIDE is not picking up the scala version you are specifying. Since you say that you tried it with 2.10.4, it probably still has that cached or set somewhere and it's failing because it cannot find the specified class.